# Trying to figure out how to make asynchronous GET requests with Curl_multi. Code not returning expected stuff but not giving errors either

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I'm currently trying to figure out how to make asynchronous GET requests in PHP. I was pointed towards Curl_multi but I am having a hard time figuring it out.

I have an array with 3 URLs to which I want to make the GET requests. Sadly my code gives no errors, however, the returned result is just an array with 3 empty elements `" "`. I'm not too familiar with Curl but I checked a couple of articles on how to use it and cobbled together this.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
public function getVisited(){
    $finalPlaces = ['https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=1&key=',
                    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=2&key=',
                    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=3&key='];

    $curly = array();
    $result = array();
    $mh = curl_multi_init();

    foreach ($finalPlaces as $id => $d) {
        $curly[$id] = curl_init();

        $url = $d;
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
    }

    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while($running > 0);

    foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
        $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
    }

    curl_multi_close($mh);
}
```

Comment: Does an individual cURL request work for the URLs? Goes curl_getinfo give you any help?

Comment: Hmmmm turns out I was getting an error because my server didn't have SSL certificate so as soon as I added curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); it worked.